# problem with jqmodal inside an update panel

Tags: updatepanel, jqmodal

I have a control that I need to display as a page or as a modal dialog.
In the page_load event I look to see if the modal property is set and if so, I register a script to invoke jqmodal.  Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Modal)                                         // Show as a modal dialog
    {

        selector.Attributes.Add("class", "jqmWindow");
        selector.Attributes.Add("style", "width:1100px;height:600px;");
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$().ready(function() { $(" + "'#" + selector.ClientID + "').jqm({ modal: true }).jqmShow();});</script>";
        //script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">confirm('hello');</script>";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"duh",script,false);
    }
}
```

This control is used on a page that has an update panel.
This all works well in Firefox and IE for the INITAL page load and any refreshes.  However when I postback I get problems in IE and FF:
In IE, the div that represents the modal (in this case, selector) is shifted down and to the right about 500 px.

In firefox, the darkened area around the div becomes progressively darker with each postback.

**If I remove the update panel from the host page (it's actually in the master page) this code works.**

I have tried not executing the above code on postback but that simply disables jqmodal.  I'm really stumped If anyone can help with this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on PostBack, the jQuery div is moved down and to the right.  The div after page load looks like this (renders correctly):

```
DIV class="jqmWindow jqmID1" id=selector style="DISPLAY: block; Z-INDEX: 3000; WIDTH: 1100px; HEIGHT: 600px" _jqm="1" jQuery1238701349279="3">
```

After Async PostBack it looks like this (renders incorrectly):

```
DIV class="jqmWindow jqmID2" id=selector style="DISPLAY: block; Z-INDEX: 3000; WIDTH: 1100px; TOP: 146px; HEIGHT: 600px" _jqm="2" jQuery1238701490978="5">
```

Removing the update panel solves this problem......I don't know that it is the problem.

I created a project with some pages with the just relevent code.  The pages are site.master, List.aspx/cs and PartSelector.ascx/cs

```
// site.master - nothing in codebehind
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="http://localhost/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/Scripts/jqueryUI/ui/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" > </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:updatepanel id="upmaincontent" runat="server" updatemode="conditional">
            <contenttemplate>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


// list.aspx
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" CodeFile="List.aspx.cs" Inherits="List" Title="Parts Master List" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" tagprefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/PartSelector.ascx" TagName="PartSelector" TagPrefix="sam"  %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server" />
    <center>
        <div><center><h3><%= "Part Selector" %></h3></center></div>
        <div>
            <center>
                <sam:PartSelector ID="PartSelector1" runat="server" Modal="true" ActiveOnly="false" />
            </center>
        </div>
    </center>
</asp:Content>




// list.aspx.cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.DynamicData;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public partial class List : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PartSelector1.ActivateSelector("");
        }
    }
}


// PartSelector.ascx
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PartSelector.ascx.cs" Inherits="PartSelector" %>

<link href="http://localhost/Scripts/jqModal/jqModal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://localhost/Scripts/jqModal/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var IsModal = false;                            // Initialize a variable to indicate if the page is to be displayed inside a jqModal dialaog
    $().ready(function() { displayPage(); });       // Execute dispalyPage when the dom is ready

    function displayPage() {
        confirm('displaypage');     
        IsModal = <%= this.Modal ? "true" : "false" %>  // Set IsModal based on a property in codebehind

        if(IsModal)
        {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(displayPageAsync);     // handle async postbacks
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler); // clean up before starting an async postback
            $("#selector").addClass("jqmWindow");                           // add some css to resize the display to fit the modal dialog
            $("#selector").css({width:"1100px", height: "600px"});
            $("#selector").jqm({ modal: true, onHide: hidejqm }).jqmShow();
        }
    }

    function displayPageAsync(sender, args)
    {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

        if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack() ) {             // Prevent displayPage from being called twice on the initial page load
            confirm('page loaded, async postback.');
            displayPage();
        }
    }

    function beginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        confirm('begin async postback');
        $("#selector").jqmHide();   // Hide a dialog from last postback 
    }

    function hidejqm(hash) {
        confirm('hidejqm');
        hash.w.fadeOut('2000', function() { hash.o.remove(); });
    }
</script>

<div id="selector">
    <center>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Click here to postback" OnClick="Postback_Click"></asp:LinkButton><br /><br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="CancelButton_Click" CssClass="CommandButton"></asp:LinkButton>
    </center>
</div>




// PartSelector.ascx.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Linq.Expressions;


public partial class PartSelector : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public bool Modal { get; set; }


    public void ActivateSelector(string searchString)
    {
        this.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void Postback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 1;
    }

}
```